# Possible Output Sampling Rates in Audio Units

Tags: iphone, ios, core-audio, audiounit

I am trying to set different sampling rates (like 32kHz, 24kHz etc..) to the input stream of Remote I/O audio unit. But the output is always played at one of these sampling rates - 
22.05kHz, 33.1kHz, 11.0kHz irrespective of what I set. And surprisingly, when I call     `AudioUnitGetProperty` on `kAudioUnitScope_Output` for `kAudioUnitProperty_SampleRate`, it always returns 44.1kHz

```
- (void)startToneUnit
{
    AudioComponentDescription defaultOutputDescription;
    defaultOutputDescription.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
    defaultOutputDescription.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_RemoteIO;
    defaultOutputDescription.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
    defaultOutputDescription.componentFlags = 0;
    defaultOutputDescription.componentFlagsMask = 0;

        // Get the default playback output unit
    AudioComponent defaultOutput = AudioComponentFindNext(NULL, &defaultOutputDescription);
    NSAssert(defaultOutput, @"Can't find default output");

        // Create a new unit based on this that we'll use for output
    OSErr err = AudioComponentInstanceNew(defaultOutput, &toneUnit);
    NSAssert1(toneUnit, @"Error creating unit: %hd", err);

        // Set our tone rendering function on the unit
    AURenderCallbackStruct input;
    input.inputProc = RenderTone;
    input.inputProcRefCon = (__bridge void *)(self);
    err = AudioUnitSetProperty(toneUnit,
                               kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback,
                               kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                               0,
                               &input,
                               sizeof(input));
    NSAssert1(err == noErr, @"Error setting callback: %hd", err);

        // Set the format to 32 bit, single channel, floating point, linear PCM
    const int four_bytes_per_float = 4;
    const int eight_bits_per_byte = 8;

    AudioStreamBasicDescription streamFormat;
    streamFormat.mSampleRate = SAMPLE_RATE;
    streamFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;
    streamFormat.mFormatFlags =
    kAudioFormatFlagsNativeFloatPacked;
    streamFormat.mBytesPerPacket = four_bytes_per_float;
    streamFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
    streamFormat.mBytesPerFrame = four_bytes_per_float;
    streamFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
    streamFormat.mBitsPerChannel = four_bytes_per_float * eight_bits_per_byte;
    err = AudioUnitSetProperty (toneUnit,
                                kAudioUnitProperty_StreamFormat,
                                kAudioUnitScope_Input,
                                0,
                                &streamFormat,
                                sizeof(AudioStreamBasicDescription));

    NSAssert1(err == noErr, @"Error setting stream format: %hd", err);

        // Stop changing parameters on the unit
    err = AudioUnitInitialize(toneUnit);
    NSAssert1(err == noErr, @"Error initializing unit: %hd", err);

        // Start playback
    err = AudioOutputUnitStart(toneUnit);
    NSAssert1(err == noErr, @"Error starting unit: %hd", err);

    Float64 outSampleRate = 0.0;
    UInt32 size = sizeof(Float64);
    AudioUnitGetProperty (toneUnit,
                          kAudioUnitProperty_SampleRate,
                          kAudioUnitScope_Output,
                          0,
                          &outSampleRate,
                          &size);
    NSLog(@"Output sample rate is now at %f Hz", outSampleRate);

   }
```

What are all the possible output sampling rates supported for Audio Units? Any reference to Apple's documentation on this will be greatly helpful

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`AudioUnit`s, in general, can run at whatever sample rate you specify.  The `RemoteIO` (or HAL on Mac OS X) AudioUnits, being facades for hardware, are more restricted -- varispeed  clock generators, sample rate generators that can run at any arbitrary sample rate, are very expensive and generally not appropriate for telephones :)

Different iOS hardware, models of hardware, or lines of hardware or revisions may support different sample rates.  `RemoteIO` just accepts the rate you request and sets the onboard converter to the rate that is closest to the one you request.  You always have to do a `AudioUnitGetProperty` to see what you're actually getting.  If you want to record or work at a different rate, you need to then employ an converter plugin.

Comment: Thanks!!! But calling the `AudioUnitGetProperty` for sampling rate always returns 44.1kHz even though audio is actually being played at a different frequency like 22.05kHz or 33.1kHz or 11kHz (found these frequencies by dividing total samples rendered by duration of audio playback). Any thing wrong with my code??

Comment: A detail--- you know when you set the input properties of RemoteIO you must address them to bus `1`, right?  When you're doing all those `SetProperty`calls to `kAudioUnitScope_Input` but bus `0`, they aren't setting the properties on the correct entity.